# Scala getResource from Classpath

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2

I have a config file in my src/main/resources folder and I would like to load this, and what I did to do that is:

```
  println(getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("db.conf"))
  val path = getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("db.conf").getPath
  val DB_CONFIG = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(path))
  println(DB_CONFIG)

  // Prepare the MongoDB Connection credentials
  val prepareMongoDBConfig: Option[(String, Int, String, String, String)] = for {

    host   <- Option(DB_CONFIG.getString("database_host"))
    port   <- Option(DB_CONFIG.getInt   ("database_port"))
    user   <- Option(DB_CONFIG.getString("database_user"))
    pass   <- Option(DB_CONFIG.getString("database_pass"))
    dbname <- Option(DB_CONFIG.getString("database_name"))
  } yield (host, port, user, pass, dbname)
```

Where the db.conf is located under the src/main/resources folder. I package this as a jar and this jar is included as a library in the Play project. When I unit test this, it works fine but when running from within the Play server, I get to see to following:

```
20:41:10.216 [play-internal-execution-context-1] INFO  play - Application started (Dev)
jar:file:/development/play-server/lib/server-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/db.conf
Config(SimpleConfigObject({}))
```

As it can be seen that the SimpleConfigObject is empty. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I think I see. You are trying to load the resource from the jar as a file, but it isn't a file, it's a path in the jar. It works when you aren't packaged up as a jar because in that case it is a separate file.

Try `ConfigFactory.parseResources("db.conf")` or `ConfigFactory.parseResourcesAnySyntax("db")` perhaps.

More generic troubleshooting ideas for others who may have a problem like this:

- Try setting `-Dconfig.trace=loads` when you launch the prod version and it may have some helpful output on stderr.
- Unpack the jar with `jar xf` and be sure it has the expected db.conf in the expected place.

Comment: If I omit the .conf part in the db.conf and use the load method as ConfigFactory.load("db"), it loads the file and the properties are set and accessible. It is fine for me but at the same time, it lods other system properties as well which I do not actually want.

Comment: Cool. I will give it a try and post my findings!